# Solution of a typical equation with surds power

Tags: exponential-function, radicals

I was attempting to find a solution for the equation 
$1 + 12^\sqrt{x} = 9^\sqrt{x} + 10^\sqrt{x}$. By the trial and error, I found a solution $ x = 9$. Is there any method to solve these equation?

Comment: Let $y=\sqrt{x}$, $y\geq0$.

Comment: I tried with this transformation. But did not work.

Comment: What do you mean by "it did not work"? It dramatically simplifies the problem.

Comment: By 'did not work', I meant this transformation did not solve the problem. DO you get the solution AT ALL  by this method?

Comment: I mean, it's easy to show that no solution exists with $y>3$, and via intermediate value theorem, you can prove that there are at most two solutions to this equation. I won't do the rest, but once you find the range in which a second solution might exist, the problem will become easier.

Comment: I have found two real solutions

Comment: The second solution is easy, $x=0$

Comment: Except the 'trial and error method', is there any general way to solve this equation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Step 1.** Set $\,y=\sqrt{x}$, and obtain the equation
$$
f(y)=12^y-10^y-9^y+1=0
$$

**Step 2.** Show that $f(y)<0$, if $y\in(0,3)$, $f(y)>0$, if $y>3$ or $y<0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I got it now.